# Check if hostname is in Array

Tags: powershell

I have an array with exclusions like:

```
$hosts= @("*iphone*","*Samsung*")
```

I would like to exclude this hosts from my dhcp-leases like:

```
Get-DhcpServerv4Lease -ComputerName $dhcp_server -ScopeId $scope.ScopeID |ForEach-Object {
        if(($_) -and $_.Hostname -notlike $hostnames -and $_.ClientID -notlike $clientids  -and $_.Description -notlike $descriptions) {
do something
```

When I work without array like:

```
$leases += Get-DhcpServerv4Lease -ComputerName $dhcp_server -ScopeId $scope.ScopeID | 
           where {$_.Hostname -notlike "*iphone*" -and $_.Hostname -notlike...
```

this works already fine.

So I've no idea, why this does not work when the exclusions are in an array instead of the where clause

Comment: well, the problem seems to be that you named the collection `$Hosts` but you used `$HostNames` in your comparison. [*grin*] ///// have you thot about using a regex test instead? `-notmatch 'iphone|samsung'` would give the same result and may be ever so slightly faster.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

AFAIK you should not use `-notlike` to compare against an array.
You can do it using the Regular Expression operator `-notmatch`. For that, you combine the options in the array with the regex **OR** character `|`.

```
$hosts= ("iphone","Samsung" | ForEach-Object { [Regex]::Escape($_) }) -join '|'
```

results in `iphone|Samsung`.

<sup>Note the use of `[Regex]::Escape()` to make sure Regex special characters get escaped so they are seen as literals.</sup>

With that, use a Where-Object clause like this:

```
Where-Object {$_.Hostname -notmatch $hosts}
```

Do the same for `$clientids` and `$descriptions`